# Get count while combining fields

Tags: mysql

Edit: I changed the table. Please see updated table:

In my sample table

```
post            status      
-------------   -------------
post1           delivered
post2           undelivered
post3           delayed
post4           delivered
post5           undelivered
```

Is it possible to get the number of `delivered` and the number of `undelivered` + `delayed` combined in a single query?

Like this:

```
post            status      
-------------   -------------
delivered       2
undelivered     3
```

Comment: Do you care if you get the results in 1 row? Or 2 rows is okay? If 2, then you can just use a UNION between 2 queries. Does this help?

Comment: what is your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(status = 'delivered', 1, 0)) as `delivered_count`,
    COUNT(postid) as `all_count`
FROM
    table
```

Should work fine. This accounts there only being `delivered` and `undelivered` statuses - if there's more, but you still only want to count these two, you can do the following:

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(status = 'delivered', 1, 0)) as `delivered_count`,
    SUM(IF(status = 'delivered' OR status = 'undelivered', 1, 0)) as `all_count`
FROM
    table
```

If you want `delivered` and `undelivered` counts individually, you can use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(postid),
    status
FROM
    table
WHERE
    status IN ('delivered', 'undelivered')
GROUP BY
    status
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY status = 'delivered'
ORDER BY status = 'delivered' DESC
```

This will result in

```
count of delivered
count of everything else
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `delivered`, `undelivered`, and `delayed` are the only available status,

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'delivered' THEN 1 END) `delivered`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status <> 'delivered' THEN 1 END) `delayed + undelivered`
FROM    tableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6edbd/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════════════════╗
║ DELIVERED ║ DELAYED + UNDELIVERED ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════╣
║         2 ║                     3 ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

based on your edit, you want it to have multiple rows,

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN status = 'delivered' THEN 'delivered'
                  ELSE 'undelivered'
        END post,
        COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY CASE WHEN status = 'delivered' THEN 'delivered'
                  ELSE 'undelivered'
           END
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6edbd/6)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════════╦════════════╗
║    POST     ║ TOTALCOUNT ║
╠═════════════╬════════════╣
║ delivered   ║          2 ║
║ undelivered ║          3 ║
╚═════════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: My table also has a `created DATETIME` field although not shown here. Using your query, is it possible to show each sum grouped by month?

Comment: yes it is. which of the query do you want me to modify by grouping them by month?

Comment: The first query you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only three status, and you want one row with the count of delivered items, and one row with the count of undelivered+delayed items, you could use this query:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN status = 'delivered' THEN status
       ELSE 'undelivered+delayed' END status,
  COUNT(*) cnt
FROM
  yourtable
GROUP BY
  CASE WHEN status = 'delivered' THEN status
       ELSE 'undelivered+delayed' END
```